# Playing embedded YouTube Videos

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I have a WebView app that includes embedded YouTube videos on a page. But when I go to that page, it gives me an error with a whole bunch of text. I have searched the internet for the past week but with no luck. Can somebody please help me?
P.S. I am new to Android, so snippets would REALLY help :)

Here's the error:

```
vp.events.addOnDOMLoadHandler(function()
{vp.website.createVideoPlayer('mediaPlayer_cff30e24_42e1_4eb6
'http://youtube.com/v/XXXX', 569, 485, false);});
You need Flash Player in order to view this.
```

Comment: First: Check if that video works proper on a browser. Then check on the app.

Second: Please paste the errors

Comment: It does not work in the browser.

Comment: It does work on other peoples phones though

Comment: then its a problem of the phone you are testing it on.

Comment: On other phones it works on the browser but not on the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well from CommonsWare

> You cannot show them embedded except perhaps on devices that have Flash.

here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2292459/1084764

however you can override the urlLoading on your `webviewclient`

I suggest you reading the whole post : [play youtube video in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292086/play-youtube-video-in-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Adobe Flash Player on your phone is indeed working properly.

Comment: I cannot install Flash Player on my phone. I have a LG Optimus Q (LGL55C)