# play youtube video in android

Tags: android, youtube, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an android app and i want to play streaming video from youtube. I read posts like this: [How to play YouTube video in my Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application)
I tried with that source:

```
  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsDYIgX_gDs")));
```

i got video in WebView, i can heard sound but no pictures..Also that is not what i want because i want video to start automatically when the activity start, without clicking Button play(because i want also to add some counters,timers.. for other treatments).
Then, i tried whith MediaPlayer:

```
 String FILE_PATH="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsDYIgX_gDs";
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(FILE_PATH);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```

Hopping here having a control on video start by `mp.start();` . But i have these errors:

```
05-20 15:36:36.279: ERROR/HTTPStream(33): recv failed, errno = 11 (Try again)
05-20 15:36:36.808: ERROR/HTTPDataSource(33): HTTP request failed w/ http status 303
05-20 15:36:36.808: ERROR/HTTPDataSource(33): retrying connection failed
05-20 15:36:41.834: ERROR/HTTPStream(33): recv failed, errno = 11 (Try again)
05-20 15:36:48.389: ERROR/HTTPStream(33): recv failed, errno = 11 (Try again)
05-20 15:36:54.913: ERROR/HTTPStream(33): recv failed, errno = 11 (Try again)
05-20 15:36:54.913: ERROR/HTTPStream(33): recv failed, errno = 9 (Bad file number)
05-20 15:36:54.918: ERROR/HTTPStream(33): recv failed, errno = 9 (Bad file number)
05-20 15:36:54.918: ERROR/HTTPStream(33): recv failed, errno = 9 (Bad file number)
05-20 15:36:54.918: ERROR/MediaPlayer(6392): error (1, -2147483648)
05-20 15:36:55.219: ERROR/MediaPlayer(6392): start called in state 0
05-20 15:36:55.219: ERROR/MediaPlayer(6392): error (-38, 0)
05-20 15:36:55.228: ERROR/MediaPlayer(6392): Error (-38,0)
```

Can someone help plz?

Comment: Are you trying this on emulator or on live device?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Start intent to :

```
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse(String.format("http://www.youtube.com/v/%s", 
url.substring("vnd.youtube:".length(),n)));
```

For deeper learning try out the following question : [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292086/play-youtube-video-in-webview), and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent).

Comment: Thank you eric, but this gives me the same way to do as i did! i will check in your links suggestions to see