# Opening youtube videos in a webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to open youtube videos in a webview.
In a webview I go to the page of a video in youtube and when I try to play the video, it doesnot start. Is it possible to play youtube videos in a webview?
If it is not, how can I direct my application to open the video with native media player of the phone.

Comment: take a look at this SO post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292086/play-youtube-video-in-webview

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webview);

String playVideo= "<html><body>Youtube video .. <br> <iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"640\" height=\"385\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/bIPcobKMB94\" frameborder=\"0\"></body></html>";

myWebView.loadData(playVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

And yes dont forget to add permission into your manifest:

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's gonna help, I just should find how to trigger this when the video is clicked.

Comment: loadData on click event will help you to trigger this when the video is clicked

Comment: @AkasG this helped me alot. Thank you. By the way is it possible to get the video id when i click on it in webview and then use this method to play the video?

Comment: Anyway, any idea how to do the thing I mentioned?

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url