# Android, WebView not playing YouTube videos

Tags: java, android, webview, youtube

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;

import com.google.ads.AdView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class Youtube extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    private ProgressBar progress;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView4);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar4);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/");
    }

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.ver_web, menu);

        return true;
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {  

        @Override

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

               view.loadUrl(url);

               return true;
        }

        @Override

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Youtube.this.progress.setProgress(100);

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

       }

        @Override

       public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

           progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

           Youtube.this.progress.setProgress(0);

           super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
       }
   }

   public void setValue(int progress) {

       this.progress.setProgress(progress);       
   }

   @Override

   public void onBackPressed() {

       // Check if there's history

       if (this.webView.canGoBack())

           this.webView.goBack();

       else

           super.onBackPressed();

   }

public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


//Request an ad

AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

}

}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706580/youtube-video-not-playing-in-webview

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong?  How are you entering the URL?  And have you used a debugger to check whether `view.loadUrl` is actually getting called?

Comment: No, it's unfair to close this as a duplicate.  If you look at the only answer to that other question, the OP clearly stated that it didn't work.  It looks like he/she may have only accepted the answer out of charity.  It seems doubtful therefore, that this question has a working answer yet.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: @DavidWallace that question was accepted because it provided answer to the original question and also provided answers to couple of more questions in the comments. Please read all the comments.

Comment: @AlexP I read them all, thank you, before I voted to reopen this question.