# Youtube link in html file

Tags: android, html, video, android-webview

In webView, I am loading a html file. The file contains text, images and a youtube link. Text and the images are displayed just by loadUrl() method, but video is not being played. How should I get the link and play video.

Format in which link is present in html file is :

```
<p style="text-align: center; margin: 0px;">

        <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="300" height="169" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4H0fTwtPLfo" allowfullscreen frameborder="0">

        </iframe>

        </p>
```

Please guide me.

**EDIT**

loading html file:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+htmlFile);
webView.setWebViewClient(new VideoWebViewClient());
```

VideoWebViewClient class:

```
private class VideoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2**

I am able to play video by adding following lines of code:

```
WebSettings webSetting = webView.getSettings();
webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSetting.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
webSetting.setAllowContentAccess(true);

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/"+htmlFile);
webView.setWebViewClient(new VideoWebViewClient());
```

I want to play video in full screen, but the full screen button freeze the video. Can anyone help?

Comment: is video display and not start automaticly or no display ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [YouTube Video not playing in WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706580/youtube-video-not-playing-in-webview)

Comment: there is no diaplay. In place of video there is a black box.

Comment: I am working with dynamic activity. Thus I don't have layout to add custom view as shown in example. I have tried with some code but it didn't help me. See my edit code and guide me.