# Youtube videos don't show up in WebView

Tags: android, video, webview

I just added a webview to my app to load a simple article with a video on it and some text.
The text shows up as it should but it's as if the video is not even an invisible element.

```
    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webArticle);
    browser.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    WebSettings settings = browser.getSettings();
    settings.setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
    settings.setBlockNetworkImage(false);
    settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    browser.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

At first ,You need to add this

```
getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
getSettings().setUserAgent(USER_MOBILE);
```

Then Add to the **Application Manifest File (Below Permission):**

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

For demo code **[Play YouTube video in WebView](http://fancifulandroid.blogspot.in/2013/01/play-youtube-video-in-webview-without.html)**

> [play youtube video in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292086/play-youtube-video-in-webview)

Comment: I also have hardware acceleration. It seems no solution for this works for me!